# SQL - Filter Weekend Data, but include half day monday (up till noon)

Tags: sql

I'm currently running data (2 datasets) to pull both weekday data and weekend data.  Below is the logic I'm using for both in my 'WHERE' statement....

Weekend:

```
AND(dw, dd.date) NOT IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday')
```

Weekday:

```
AND DATENAME(dw, dd.date) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
```

I was recently asked to include half of Monday on my weekend data (up till 12pm Monday).  I need help updating my where clause to include half day monday on my Weekend SQL statement.  To be clear, weekends should include all day Saturday, Sunday and 12am to 12pm Monday.

Thanks!

Comment: What date type is dw and dd.date?

Comment: Copy-and-paste issue in the first WHERE clause?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (DATENAME is a product specific function.)